# Running executable from desktop given me: *ERR* IO-21 invalid STATUS specifier for given file

Tags: java, runtime-error, executable

I have been trying to run

> **C:\Users\Luis\Desktop\RESEARCHGUIPROJECT\ResearchGUI\CHEMKED\CHEMKED_SOLVER.exe**

using java or having java use the command prompt to run this executable. Now I believe I was to able to get java to the file but when it runs it the executable gives me ***ERR*** ***IO-21 invalid STATUS specifier for given file***.

I have ran the executable from the DOS window and usually when that code is given it means the input file has been specified incorrectly. To give background on the solver what it does is read from a file named ***solverfilepath.txt*** and in that file a file directory is given to where the file is located. This file is the solvers input named ***SOLTMP.txt***.

This error only occurs when I run java but doesn't occur when I run it manually from the command window.

I don't know if there might be a way when java is running this program to also have it open the command window to see the executable run in the command prompt.

Any suggestions?

```
    int i = 1;
    while(finalTime < 1.0000){

        try{

        // Execute CHEMKED solver

        // Added 07/06/2013 from StackOverFlow
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String[] CHEMKED = {"C:\\Users\\Luis\\Desktop\\RESEARCHGUIPROJECT\\ResearchGUI\\CHEMKED\\CHEMKED_SOLVER.exe"};
        Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CHEMKED); 

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

        String line=null;

        while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("*****");
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        int exitVal;
            exitVal = pr.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);

        } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            inputFile3 = new Scanner(new FileReader("CHEMKED\\SOLTMP.txt"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

        try{
            copyFile = new Formatter(new File("CHEMKED\\output-ring1_"+ i +".txt"));
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

        //copy SOLTMP content to temporary file
        while(inputFile3.hasNextLine()){
            fileLine = inputFile3.nextLine();
            copyFile.format("%s%n",fileLine);
        }

        copyFile.close();
        inputFile3.close();

         // Added 07/05/2013
         initialTime+= 0.10;
         finalTime+= 0.10;

         // Added 07.03
         updateFile();

    i++;      
    }
```

So here is what I have added so far simply similar to what was done on javaWorld. I haven't had the chance to run it yet, but just seeing if I am headed in the right direction.

```
class StreamGobbler extends Thread
{
InputStream is;
String type;
OutputStream os;

StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type)
{
    this(is, type, null);
}
StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type, OutputStream redirect)
{
    this.is = is;
    this.type = type;
    this.os = redirect;
}

public void run()
{
    try
    {
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        if (os != null)
            pw = new PrintWriter(os);

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line=null;
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (pw != null)
                pw.println(line);
            System.out.println(type + ">" + line);    
        }
        if (pw != null)
            pw.flush();
    } catch (IOException ioe)
        {
        ioe.printStackTrace();  
        }
    }
}

public void chemked(String args[])  {

    int i = 1;
    while(finalTime < 1.0000)   {
    if (args.length < 1)
    {
        System.out.println("USAGE java GoodWinRedirect <outputfile>");
        System.exit(1);
    }
        try{

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(args[0]);

        String[] CHEMKED = { "C:\\Users\\Luis\\Desktop\\RESEARCHGUIPROJECT\\ResearchGUI\\CHEMKED\\CHEMKED_SOLVER.exe"}; 

        Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CHEMKED); 

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

        // any error message
        StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new 
            StreamGobbler(pr.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");            



        // any output
        StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new 
            StreamGobbler(pr.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT", fos);

        // start them off
        errorGobbler.start();
        outputGobbler.start();

        String line=null;

        while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("*****");
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        int exitVal;
            exitVal = pr.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

        } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            inputFile3 = new Scanner(new FileReader("CHEMKED\\SOLTMP.txt"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

        try{
            copyFile = new Formatter(new File("CHEMKED\\output-ring1_"+ i +".txt"));
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

        //copy SOLTMP content to temporary file
        while(inputFile3.hasNextLine()){
            fileLine = inputFile3.nextLine();
            copyFile.format("%s%n",fileLine);
        }

        copyFile.close();
        inputFile3.close();

         // Added 07/05/2013
         initialTime+= 0.10;
         finalTime+= 0.10;

         // Added 07.03
         updateFile();

    i++;      
    }
  }
```

Let me know thank you.

**SOLUTION:**

```
    int i = 1;
    while(finalTime < 1.0000)   {

        try{

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Luis\\Desktop\\RESEARCHGUIPROJECT\\ResearchGUI\\CHEMKED\\error" +i+".txt");

        String[] CHEMKED = { "C:\\Users\\Luis\\Desktop\\RESEARCHGUIPROJECT\\ResearchGUI\\CHEMKED\\CHEMKED_SOLVER.exe", "SOLTMP.txt"}; 

        //Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CHEMKED); 

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(CHEMKED);

        builder.directory(new File("C:\\Users\\Luis\\Desktop\\RESEARCHGUIPROJECT\\ResearchGUI\\CHEMKED"));

        builder.redirectError();

        Process pr =   builder.start();

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

        // any error message?
        StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new 
            StreamGobbler(pr.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");            

        // any output?
        StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new 
           StreamGobbler(pr.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT", fos);

        // kick them off
        errorGobbler.start();
        outputGobbler.start();

        int exitVal;
            exitVal = pr.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

        } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            inputFile3 = new Scanner(new FileReader("CHEMKED\\SOLTMP.txt"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

        try{
            copyFile = new Formatter(new File("CHEMKED\\output-ring1_"+ i +".txt"));
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

        //copy SOLTMP content to temporary file
        while(inputFile3.hasNextLine()){
            fileLine = inputFile3.nextLine();
            copyFile.format("%s%n",fileLine);
        }

        copyFile.close();
        inputFile3.close();

         // Added 07/05/2013
         initialTime+= 0.10;
         finalTime+= 0.10;

         // Added 07.03
         updateFile();
    i++;      
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using a ProcessBuilder for this, you should be gobbling and showing the error stream as well. This line `Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();` does nothing other than mislead.

Comment: I read the article from java world about gobbling and what not but I don't know how I can apply it to my code.

Comment: You apply it just like it was likely explained in the article. You get the error stream, you put it in a BufferedReader and you display it. You are already doing this with the InputStream, so I'm confused as to why or how you're confused. But for both you will need to use background threads.

Comment: maybe it's the way they presented it in the document I'll look it over some more and see what I come up.

Comment: I just edited my comment see what you think.

Comment: You need to run the code to see if it changes the observed behavior.

Comment: i ran it and it still gave me the same error code :/

Comment: :(  What would your command line look like if you were running this program from the command line?

Comment: when i want to run chemked my class in java do i say. chemked(); or chemked(args[0])

Comment: How you run it depends on what you're trying to do. If your code is in an instance method or in the constructor, you will need to call an *appropriate* constructor, and then call the instance method if it is needed. If instead you are calling a static method of the class, then all you need to do is call the static method *on the class*. It's the same for any Java program. This is no different.

Comment: for example i posted how the executable runs from the command prompt

Comment: You state `" when that code is given it means the input file has been specified incorrectly."` yet you don't specify the input file on the command line. Have you checked to see if the program can run with a command line parameter that specifies the input file? If so, then your Java code for your ProcessBuilder (and again you should use this) should reflect this.

Comment: Time = 0.10000    Step = 00

STOP = Program terminated

Comment: I couldn't post a picture but this is what it gives when it is ran on the command prompt

Comment: well the input file is taken care of because it is already specified in the appropriate folder so there is no need or way for me to specify it via java. it would be easier if it were that way but it's the way the executable was programmed

Comment: Ill change to process builder rather than runtime. and see what happens

Comment: `"well the input file is taken care of because it is already specified in the appropriate folder so there is no need or way for me to specify it via java."` -- don't make any assumptions such as this until your program is running smoothly. Until then, it should be obvious that all bets are off. ProcessBuilder is more robust but won't solve your problem. Your problem may very well be with the assumption that you've made.

Comment: so how do i tell my executable to run SOLTMP.txt?

Comment: I am not familiar with your executable. **Again**, have you checked the documentation for the executable? Can it be run with **command line parameters**, parameters that specify the file to load?

Comment: see the thing is I put the solver into one directory. then i put a file named solverfilepath.txt in the same directory. that file (solverfilepath) says SOLTMP.txt is in the directory. so CHEMKED reads in the solverfilepath and then reads in soltmp and runs. without solverfilepath in the same directory chemked can't run

Comment: ive tried getting access to the solver but it doesn't allow me or i don't know how to access it.

Comment: no i don't believe it can be ran with command line parameters that i know of. I'm still an apprentice with java and coding overall

Comment: Where is your jar file that holds your Java code located? Is it in the same directory as your CHEMKED_SOLVER.exe file? Consider using a ProcessBuilder, and setting its working directory to be the same as that which holds your CHEMKED_SOLVER.exe file.

Comment: my java file and chemked solver are two different directories. I will locate my java file in the same folder as the CHEMKED_SOLVER.exe

Comment: No -- don't put the java file anywhere near the exe file. You don't run java files, you run class files or better jar files. Regardless, the key I think you should try is to set the working directory of the process to be the same as the exe file. Please see my answer for a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you for all your help ill let you know my outcomes

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: Yeah I read that and applied it and what Hovercraft recommended as well and I got my code working the way I want it too.  Thank you very much I will post my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, consider using a ProcessBuilder and setting its working directory to be the same location as your executive file. Something like:

```
  String path = "C:/Users/Luis/Desktop/RESEARCHGUIPROJECT/ResearchGUI/CHEMKED/";
  String app = "CHEMKED_SOLVER.exe";
  List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
  // command.add(path);
  command.add(app);
  ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
  processBuilder.directory(new File(path));
  processBuilder.redirectError();
  Process process = processBuilder.start();

  BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
  String line = "";
  while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(line);
  }
```

Comment: @user2537150: you're welcome. The key lesson from this is that when calling an outside process like this, you must take care of making sure that the processes working directory is correct. I did not know this before hand, and so we both learned a thing or two from your problem. So thank you!